# DialogFlow Parameter value

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

In Dialogflow I have a Intent called GetLocation. The user can input a phrase like: I want to look at India, and the Parameter "**Location**", stores that location. For my Paramater, its name is "**Location**" and its entity is `sys.location`. Dialog Flow is able to recognize my location.

Next, Dialog Flow writes to my Firebase database and writes to the location parameter of the database (location: (location from DialogFlow). The problem is, instead of normally writing to the location parameter of the database, it also changes the "**location**" to admin-area: (location from DialogFlow). How do I stop it from renaming the location parameter in the firebase database?

Here is my Fulfillment code:

```js
function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {

       const location = agent.parameters.Location; 

    

    return admin.database().ref('locations').transaction((locations) => {
    if(locations !== null) {

      locations.place = location;
      
      
      agent.add(`Our recorded locations ` + location);

    }

    return location;
  }, function(error, isSuccess) {
    
  });
    
  //  return admin.database().ref('/locations/place').set(location);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share your fulfilment code? which writes data in the firebase database.

Comment: Okay, I just added my Fulfillment code

Answer (score 1):

```js
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function handleAge(agent) {
    const age = agent.parameters.age;

    agent.add(`Thank you...`);

    return admin.database().ref('ageInfo').transaction((ageInfo) => {
      if(ageInfo !== null) {
        let oldAverage = ageInfo.runningAverage;
        let oldTotalCount = ageInfo.totalCount;
        let newAverage = (oldAverage * oldTotalCount + age) / (oldTotalCount + 1);
        ageInfo.runningAverage = newAverge;
        ageInfo.totalCount+=1;
        agent.add(`Average age stored` + newAverage);
      }
      return ageInfo;
    }, function(error, isSuccess) {
      console.log('error: ' + isSuccess);
    });

  }


  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('AskAge', handleAge);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

URL=http://www.peterfessel.com/2018/07/google-dialogflow-chatbot-realtime-database-tutorial-read-write/

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.